# Getting values from multiple disconnected cells

Tags: excel

I'm trying to retrieve values from cells on the same row spaced 20 columns apart.

Right now I have put together the following formula to retrieve the values in the first five cells I am interested in:

```
={IF(OR(IF({1,2,3,4,5}*20+1<25,CHAR(MOD({1,2,3,4,5}*20+1,26)+64),CHAR(INT(({1,2,3,4,5}*20+1)/26)+64)&CHAR(MOD({1,2,3,4,5}*20+1,26)+64))&ROW()="OK"),"OK","N/G")}
```

The cells contain the results of calculation checks. The result if given as either "OK", "N/G" or "N/A". Right now I am interested in determining if even a single cell reports "OK", hence using the `OR` in the formula.

The problem is that whilst this gets the address of the cells correctly, they are returned as text. `OR` then does a text comparison on the addresses and the criteria and finds that none of the addresses are "OK"... which is logical, but not what I want.

I have tried using `INDIRECT()`, but that doesn't seem to work when it is in the form `={INDIRECT("A1","B2","C3")}`. Could anybody suggest a way to change the text addresses to addresses which will correctly be interpreted by the formula?

I could write some vba code for this, but I'd like to use a formula solution if possible.

Comment: Hmmm, that is an interesting suggestion, but I have no idea how I can make that work with arrays? Do you have something to demonstrate by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

With a static stagger to the columns you want to examine, you can use `MOD()` to determine their ordinal position on the worksheet.

[image]

The formula in CE2 is `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A2:$CC2=CE$1)*(MOD(COLUMN($A:$CC),20)=1)), "Yes", "No")`. Fill right and down as necessary.